# GPS Location (On/Off) event

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic2

Is there any eventListener to constantly listen to my GPS Location service? I would like my app to 'do something' once my GPS is turned off.

Currently I am using cordova plugins. And I nested a interval of 2 seconds to keep checking, I am sure that there are simpler and more code-efficient eventListener that will serve the same purpose and I would not want to use interval in my codes.

```
setInterval(function(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(function(available)
    {
        //do something if available
    },function(error){console.log(error);});
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [registerLocationStateChangeHandler()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#registerlocationstatechangehandler) from that plugin:

> Registers a function to be called when a change in Location state occurs.

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler(function(state){
    console.log("Location state changed to : " + state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the watchLocationMode(success, fail) funcion from cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation#watchlocationmodesuccess-fail

And it also has other good functions and it works when the app is in background and foreground.